# Is there limit to max number of thread in a thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, jvm

I was doing a POC for a multi threading for caching with Async thread. For this I wanted to see first that I could distribute all the thread evenly over multiple cores in a M2 Air. I ran into the problem of Max number that could be created irrespective of JVM memory allocated to execute the problem. I wanted to understand if this a problem with Mac OS or it's something I am missing ?

Consider this program :

```
 /**

This is a simple Java program to demonstrate thread pooling with fixed number of threads using the Executor framework. The program creates a fixed thread pool with a specified number of threads, assigns each thread to a processor, and prints the number of threads running on each processor. */

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public static void main(String[] args) { 
// Define number of threads 
int numThreads = 2000; 
// Create a fixed thread pool with specified number of threads 
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

// Set the number of processors to be used by the JVM
int numProcessors = 4; // Arbitrary value  
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", Integer.toString(numProcessors));

// Create a HashMap to count threads assigned to each processor
Map<Integer, Integer> processorThreadCount = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numProcessors; i++) {
    processorThreadCount.put(i, 0);
}

// Assign each thread to a processor and execute it
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    int processor = i % numProcessors;
    processorThreadCount.compute(processor, (k, v) -> v + 1);
    executor.execute(new MyThread(i));
}

// Shutdown the thread pool
executor.shutdown();

// Print the number of threads running on each processor
System.out.println("Threads per processor:");
processorThreadCount.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Processor " + k + ": " + v));

}

/**

This is a simple thread class that prints the thread ID and the processor it is running on. */

private static class MyThread implements Runnable {

private int id;

public MyThread(int id) { 
this.id = id;
}

public void run() {
System.out.println("Thread " + id + " running on processor " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
}
}
```

When I tried to increase number of thread to 9000.

```
int numThreads = 9000;
```

I encountered the problem,

```
[0.167s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes:
 stacksize: 102400k, guardsize: 16k, detached.

[0.167s]
[warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "pool-1-thread-2022"Exception in thread "main" 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reachedat 

java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) at 

java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:803) at 

java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:937) at 

java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1343)at Main.main(Main.java:151)

^C%
```

I tried increasing JVM size from `1Mb` initially to `10Mb` using `java -Xss10m Main` and then incremented it to 1 GB to try fixing the max thread count. But I ran into the problem that every time I was getting this specific thread `pool-1-thread-2022` failed to allocate with JVM memory error. **I wanted to know what is causing this limitation.**

If I am setting number of threads to 2000 shown in the program,

```
int numThreads = 2000;
```

I get this output:

```
Threads per processor:
Processor 0: 500
Processor 1: 500
Processor 2: 500
Processor 3: 500
```

Comment: The -Xss option sets the thread stack size. Reducing it (lower than 1MB) generally allows more threads to be created.

Comment: Yes, `-Xss` sets the size used by _each_ thread, so setting it higher will make it run out of memory faster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [max number of threads Mac allows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861928/max-number-of-threads-mac-allows)

Comment: I tried reducing minimum JVM heap size to 256Kb [`-Xss256k`] and max heap size to a Gb [`Xmx1g`], still I find that the max number of threads created is same. @boneill @Tim Moore

Comment: The stackOverflow question referred does not answer my question as they just speak of how limit is imposed by OS. I am think through that Ideally user should have permission increase the `guardsize `  of the thread pool. Thanks @Tim Moore

Comment: The allocation for the stack is virtual memory, so the size has no effect until the thread actually uses it. I don’t understand why you think that a limit imposed by the operating system does not apply for a Java program running under that operating system.

Comment: You might want to googgle around forr information about "Project Loom." I haven't used it myself, and I don't know what state it's in, but its end goal basically is to reduce the cost of creating new `Thread` objects in Java to where it's not significantly more expensive than creating any other kind of object. When fully implemented, it will completely change the way Java programmers think about threads.\*

Comment: \* So much so, that some authors writing about Project Loom are trying to find a new name for the concept--trying out ideas like "virtual thread" and "lightweight concurrency." I can't make up my mind whether they _should_ change the name, but I guess the desire to change it is driven by the fact that project loom breaks the 1:1 correspondance between Java threads and OS threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow when you use virtual threads, there is no need to have a pool of them anymore.